# Difference between decorating a class with [SomeAttribute] and [Some]

Tags: c#

If i have created an attribute `public class SomeAttribute : Attribute {}` and I use it like this:

```
[SomeAttribute] 
public class ClassA{}
```

or this:

```
[Some]
public class ClassA{}
```

Is there any difference? What is the underlying mechanism that allows this to work?

Comment: Implicitly it refers to same. No advantage, kinda of a short cut because at that position you can add only Attribute only. Hence y to mention it?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a difference

Answer (score 7):

By convention CLR attributes end in the word `Attribute` (they also derive from `System.Attribute`). When using an attribute, it's safe to either include that word explicitly, or to omit it (simply to reduce visual clutter) and let the compiler include it for you.

Section 17.1 of the C# Spec says:

> **17.1 Attribute classes**
>
> A class that derives from the abstract class System.Attribute, whether
>   directly or indirectly, is an attribute class. The declaration of an
>   attribute class defines a new kind of attribute that can be placed on
>   a declaration. By convention, attribute classes are named with a
>   suffix of Attribute. Uses of an attribute may either include or omit
>   this suffix.

Deep in Section 17.2, it explains that the compiler won't break the tie if both versions exist:

> **17.2 Attribute specification**
>
> ...
>
> If an attribute class is found both with and without this suffix, an
>   ambiguity is present, and a compile-time error results.

In that case, you can resolve the compile error by specifying `@Some` or `@SomeAttribute`. (The `@` represents the somewhat uncommon "verbatim identifier" feature.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no difference between the 2

Answer (score 0):

There's only a difference if there's a class named `Some`, or one named `SomeAttributeAttribute`.

Both notations will find `class SomeAttribute`.  But `[Some]` will also look for `class Some`.  And `[SomeAttribute]` will also find `class SomeAttributeAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. See sblom's answer.

Typically, if you define a custom attribute class, you append the word Attribute. For example:

```
public class SomeAttribute : System.Attribute {
}
```

When you use the class, you typically leave out the word Attribute. For example:

```
[Some()]  
public class ClassA {
}
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to say either "... you *can* leave out the word ..." or "... you *typically* leave out the word ..." or similar

Comment: @phoog; inserted typically. Thanks.